# other user's profile not populating

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, membership, profiles

I've got a weird issue going on. I'm calling the profile for another user (not the currently authenticated user) and trying to access a value.

```
 var profile = System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase.Create(username, true);
 if (profile.PropertyValues["x"] != null)
     ddlList.SelectedValue = profile.PropertyValues["x"].PropertyValue.ToString();
```

The value 'x' does exist for the user, but it's returning null. If I step through the code, and actually view the profile values before the if statement, then it works as expected. So I have to explicitly step through the code and view the value for the app to actually acknowledge it.

Comment: To me, that sounds like a classic race condition. Put a `Thread.Sleep(5000);` between getting the profile and the if. If it then runs correctly, then it is a race condition after all. _BUT PLEASE, REMOVE THE SLEEP THEN, AND COME UP WITH A BETTER SOLUTION!_ Delays can help you identify a race condition, they are NOT a solution for it.

Comment: Nope, didn't help. Good idea, though.

Comment: Then I am stumped. Your code appears to be correct. Maybe someone else will be able to help you, though.